# Finding Conflicting Combinations Using SQL

Tags: select

Say I have table called "Everyone_Loves_Relationships" which contains three fields: `Boy_Name`, `Girl_Name`, `Relationship_Status`. The list goes like this:

```
Boy_Name Girl_Name Relationship_Status
  Tony     Carol            No
  Simon    Julia            Yes
  Frank    Carol            No
  Frank    Lucy             No
  Frank    Lucy             No
  Tony     Lucy             No
  Tony     Samantha         Yes
  Frank    Carol            Yes
```

Each combination can show multiple times.

You'll notice that Frank and Carol are showing twice, once with a Yes and once with a No.

How do I design a SQL request that checks for combinations of Boy_Name&Girl_Name that have both a Yes and a No?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Boy_Name, Girl_Name
FROM Everyone_Loves_Relationships
GROUP BY Boy_Name, Girl_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Relationship_Status) = 2
```

This query assumes that none another value (including NULL) is present in `Relationship_Status` field. If this is not true then replace the condition with

```sql
HAVING SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Relationship_Status = 'Yes'
                         THEN 1
                         WHEN Relationship_Status = 'No'
                         THEN 2
                         ELSE 3
                         END) < 3
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: If Relationship_Status had 10 different possible values but we wanted to only query for the combinations of names that have (either 'Yes' or 'Yesss') AND (either 'No' or Nooo'), I assume we could use your second example and tweak it?

Comment: Also, thank you for the editing my question. I'm a new member and didn't know how to properly word/format my question.

Comment: *I assume we could use your second example and tweak it?* Yes. For example, `CASE WHEN Relationship_Status IN (1st synonims list) THEN 1 EWHEN Relationship_Status IN (2nd synonims list) THEN 2 ELSE 3 END < 1`

Comment: Perfect! Greatly appreciated.